# pytest: how to get the test status as failed when the test tear-down section fails

Tags: python, pytest

Failure/error in pytest tear-down section, does not make the test as fail, rather it reports as error, is it the default behaviour or is it according to standard? Is there a way how I can mark the test as fail when the tear-down section fails for a test?

Comment: The question is, why should a teardown have impact on the test case outcome? The test case as such has passed, and teardown is on behalf of the test driver. You should try to sort out what post-condition your test case has to meet in order to not cause an error during teardown, and add that to the test case.

Comment: why we want this way is because, when we are removing configuration in tear-down, it is sometimes expected that system may crash, during such situation tear-down will fail  and when we get the report we see test as passed, but actually we  have missed a crash, so to avoid this we want to make the test as failed even when the tear-down fails

Comment: You could add a dummy test, or name it configuration completion test, that is executed after teardown. This test case would not belong to the component, but be part of the test run to check if the system is ok.

Comment: actually we have lot of scripts already written and functioning ,so we do not want to modify anything  with them, instead i was looking for some facility already available from pytest which would  serve my purpose.

Comment: My idea is, if I get an error during teardown, I'd log this and let the test suite pass anyways. Whether this is fault of the driver or the test object has to be sorted out manually. Operator could decide to rerun test suites.

Comment: thanks yacc , for your help